# Convert PDF to XML structure

Tags: xml, pdf, converters

I would like to know a way, how I can to convert PDF files by user's mapping of elements to specific XML structure.
I looked on very much of videos or channel about convert, but all channel or videos are about commercial programm and has specific XML structure, which I can't change. I need to get own XML structure.

Are there any ways, how to achieve this? Which programming language would I use for it?

Please, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

As a start, take a look at [pdftohtml](https://www.mankier.com/1/pdftohtml)

It has an option to convert it to xml.
It will give you something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pdf2xml producer="poppler" version="0.87.0">
<page number="1" position="absolute" top="0" left="0" height="1263" width="892">
    <fontspec id="0" size="18" family="TimesNewRomanPSMT" color="#000000"/>
    <fontspec id="4" size="14" family="ArialMT" color="#000000"/>
    <image top="53" left="129" width="251" height="65" src="document-1_1.jpg"/>
    <image top="1205" left="812" width="34" height="34" src="document-1_2.jpg"/>
    <text top="58" left="135" width="5" height="16" font="0"> </text>
    <text top="602" left="144" width="261" height="17" font="4">Ontbreken van het metadataveld ‘taal’; </text>
    <text top="622" left="135" width="362" height="14" font="4">- Foutief gebruik van tabellen voor lay-out doeleinden; </text>
    <text top="639" left="135" width="243" height="14" font="4">- Afbeeldingen zonder omschrijving; </text>
    <text top="656" left="135" width="9" height="14" font="4">- </text>
 </page>
 </pdf2xml>
```

But just then it al starts.
How to translate that to something useful. Because pdf just consists of fragments of text.

To (re)create a structure out of that is a challenge.

Comment: Thank you for the very useful information. It occurred to me to map the elements differently. I understand that PHP will translate it all for me and that's it all. Is there any way how to select a specific area, which I will immediately call? For example, as a due date, etc.?

Comment: PHP? Interesting, could you be more specific? How do you do that and what is the result? For now I have no clue what you want. You need to be way more specific. Maybe clarify your needs by adding some examples to your question…

Comment: I would like to create my own system, where I map the areas that will be converted into a specific XML structure. I Need to find out how I can mark a specific area in a PDF? For example. There is a date in the PDF, I will mark it and assign an element of XML name to it. The value inside the selection is read and pasted into the element.